# Unable to Insert/Create Table from Query Results in IMPALA

Tags: sql-insert, impala

```
select * 
into temp_DB.TEMP2
from MyDb.Mytable
```

Error:

> AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 2:undefined: into MyDb.Mytable ^ Encountered: INTO Expected: FROM, LIMIT, ORDER, UNION, COMMA CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its too simple and generic.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_DB.TEMP2 AS select * from MyDb.Mytable
```